# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the following code written in Python 2 to code that is compatible with Python 3. I am receiving the following error:

> File "C:/Users/brand/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Ch‌​ange Maker.py",
>
> line 5, in  CHANGE = MONEY - PRICE
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Here is the code that I am using:

```
PRICE = input("Price of item: ")
MONEY = input("Cash tendered: ")
CHANGE = MONEY - PRICE
print ("Change: ", CHANGE)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please provide any output and/or more details about the issue you're facing.

Comment: Price of item: 28.92
Cash tendered: 64.55
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/brand/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Change Maker.py", line 5, in <module>
    CHANGE = MONEY - PRICE
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Don't put the message in a comment; edit your answer. And alway include error messages!  There is no such thing as "Just another error message".  They have critical detail.

Answer (score 4):

`input()` in Python 3 is equivalent to `raw_input()` in Python 2. Thus, `PRICE` and `MONEY` are strings, not integers as you are expecting.

To fix this, change them to integers:

```
PRICE = int(input("Price of item: "))

MONEY = int(input("Cash tendered: "))
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble after trying that too. Just another error message.

Comment: A price need not be an integer. In fact that's probably the error he's getting, if using the example inputs from the comments above. So conversion to `float` instead of `int` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I used PRICE = float(input("Price of item: "))

Comment: It worked with that. Thanks for the help! Just because with int I had to use whole numbers and couldn't use a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string in Python 3

Also for money I would recommend [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) due to [`float` lack of precision](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

```
import decimal
price = decimal.Decimal(input("Price of item: "))
money = decimal.Decimal(input("Cash tendered: "))
change = money - price
print("Change: {change}".format(change=change))
```